# Why am I getting an "undefined index" error?

Tags: php

I am getting an undefined index error from the following code:

```
<?php
  echo"<input name='type' disabled='disabled' type='text' id='type' value=$Room_type />"; 
?>


if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
   $type=$_POST['type']
}
```

Comment: is this code entirely in the same page?

Comment: Why are you `echo`ing that HTML line? Why not do `<input name='type' disabled='disabled' type='text' id='type' value='<%php echo $Room_type %>' />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is correct and not just what you provided, disabled form inputs are not submitted by browsers, that's why `$_POST['type']` is `undefined`.

Comment: I have tried removing disabled but still it gives same error there are some other form elements too and they are working fine

Comment: got it it was due to disabled only thanx